# js onclick function doesn't work django (python) project

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

i have django project and  resgitration form and submit button (class="btn") i want when click btn after print text in console but doesn't work.
this is my code -->

```
  var p = document.getElementsByClassName("btn");
  p.onclick = showAlert;

  function showAlert(event) {
    aler("onclick Event triggered!");
  }
```

this is html --->

```
<input type="submit" name="register" class="btn">
```

Comment: `aler` <-- Do you actually have the typo

Comment: getElementsByClassName returns an HTML collection

Comment: @epascarello ohh change aler to console.log but not work

Comment: document.getElementsByClassName returns an array of HTML elements, you may need to reference which element in array you want to add the onclick event. e.g. p[0].onclick = showAlert();

Comment: @Ank thank you very much!

Comment: Glad to help :)